# How can I set the config filesystem in lumen?

Tags: lumen

I wanted to configure the filesystem path in lumen, and lumen not providing the config folder set the filesystem local path how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your `bootstrap/app.php` before you register the service providers:

`$app->instance('path.config', app()->basePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');`

You can also do this for other variables like `path.storage` or `path.public`.

This is set in Laravel by default, but not done in Lumen. Therefore you need to add this yourself to the bootstrap process.